# How to create a tfs shelveset and changeset on a file?

Tags: tfs, share, changeset

I want to provide source code updates to my customers who uses my library.
Is there a way to create a TFS changeset or shelveset and copy it to a file system? Basically a file which I can share with the customer and they can apply on their local source to get my changes?

Comment: You got the problem resolved?

Answer (score 0):

If your customer has permission to access your TFS version control system, you just need to provide your customer the changesetId to ask him get specific version (via that changesetId).

If your customer doesn't have permission to access your TFS version control system, you need to first get specific version for that file to your local machine first, then send him the file (maybe via email) to ask him replace that file on his machine.

To get specific version, please right-click the file in version control and go to **Advanced** -> **Get Specific Version** -> select **Changeset** under the **Version** section. See CodexNZ's reply in this link for the details: [check out TFS at a specific change set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20087150/check-out-tfs-at-a-specific-change-set)

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is create a shelveset and then go to the tfs website to find the shelveset you have created and share the link.

I hope you would have tfs weblink like https: //tfs.**/tfs/*.

You go to the CODE tab, then you will find the explorer, changesets and shelvesets.

Click Shelvesets. The shelvesets what you have created will be populated automatically. Click the shelveset, it will give you the review board. Get the link and share it with your customer.